# How to mix AND improve this SQL sentences?

Tags: mysql, sql

First of all, I'm usign the world database for mySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/world-setup/en/index.html.

I'm trying to build a sentence that returns the least inhabited countries from each continent, showing all of them for each continent if the population is the same.

With the following sentence I manage to get the population of one the least inhabited country in each continent, but only one of them shows and the country displays incorrectly.

```
SELECT 
CASE
  WHEN Continent="Europe" THEN "Europe"
  WHEN Continent="Asia" THEN "Asia"
  WHEN Continent="North America" THEN "North America"
  WHEN Continent="South America" THEN "South America"
  WHEN Continent="Africa" THEN "Africa"
  WHEN Continent="Oceania" THEN "Oceania"
  ELSE "Antarctica"
END
  AS Area,
Name,
  CONCAT(MIN(Population),"hb") AS "N habitantes"     
FROM Country
GROUP BY Area;
```

Gives this result

```
'Africa'       , 'Angola'        , '0hb'
'Antarctica'   , 'Antarctica'    , '0hb'
'Asia'         , 'Afghanistan'   , '286000hb'
'Europe'       , 'Albania'       , '1000hb'
'North America', 'Aruba'         , '7000hb'
'Oceania'      , 'American Samoa', '0hb'
'South America', 'Argentina'     , '2000hb'
```

Well, the code is pretty dumb, I guess there has to be a way to indicate better that for each continent the query has to return the least inhabited country. I'd like to know it if it exists, as there are only 7 continents it can be done, but if they were 1000000...

With these sentence I would be able to return the least inhabited countries of the continent I indicate, for example:

```
SELECT Name,Population FROM Country WHERE Population=
(SELECT MIN(Population) FROM   Country WHERE Continent="Antarctica");
```

Returns:

'Antarctica', '0'

'French Southern territories', '0'

'Bouvet Island', '0'

'Heard Island and McDonald Islands', '0'

'British Indian Ocean Territory', '0'

'South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands', '0'

'United States Minor Outlying Islands', '0'

I think there has to be a way to mix both sentences and that it returns similar to the previous result for each continent, so it returns what I'm telling at the beginning. I mean if the only continents in the world where Antarctica and South America it should add this to the previous result:

'Falkland Islands', '2000'

'Norfolk Island', '2000'

'Niue', '2000'

'Tokelau', '2000'

I know I could use UNION making a sentence similar to the second one for each continent, but once again, that's doable only because there are just 7 continents.

Any idea of what am I missing? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

To get the names of the countries with the smallest population for each continent, you need to identify those countries. Something like this:-

```
SELECT Continent, MIN(Population) 
FROM   Country
GROUP BY Continent
```

Down side of this is it doesn't return the country name, and you can't legitimately just add the country name to the query (MySQL won't error, but the results are indeterminate).

As such you could use the above as a sub query and join it against the table, both on the continent name and the population

```
SELECT b.Continent, b.Name, b.Population
FROM
(
    SELECT Continent, MIN(Population) AS Population
    FROM Country
    GROUP BY Continent
) a
INNER JOIN Country b
ON a.Continent = b.Continent
AND a.Population = b.Population
```

Down side of this is that if more than one country has the same population in a continent then the results are going to be odd.

Another option is to use GROUP_CONCAT to put all the names together in population order, then just use SUBSTRING_INDEX to grab the first one:-

```
SELECT Continent, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Name ORDER BY Population), ',', 1), SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(Population ORDER BY Population), ',', 1)
FROM Country
GROUP BY Continent
```

Down side of this method is that if a country name contains the character used as a separator then the results might be weird (default is a comma).

Would also be possible to use a user variable to add a sequence number to the countries within a continent ordered by population, and then just grab those with a sequence number of 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
 SELECT x.continent
      , x.code
      , x.name
      , x.population 
   FROM country x 
   JOIN 
      ( SELECT continent
             , MIN(population) min_population 
          FROM country 
         GROUP 
            BY continent
      ) y 
     ON y.continent = x.continent 
    AND y.min_population = x.population;
```

Output:

```
+---------------+------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| continent     | code | name                                         | population |
+---------------+------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
| Antarctica    | ATA  | Antarctica                                   |          0 |
| Antarctica    | ATF  | French Southern territories                  |          0 |
| Antarctica    | BVT  | Bouvet Island                                |          0 |
| South America | FLK  | Falkland Islands                             |       2000 |
| Antarctica    | HMD  | Heard Island and McDonald Islands            |          0 |
| Africa        | IOT  | British Indian Ocean Territory               |          0 |
| Asia          | MDV  | Maldives                                     |     286000 |
| Antarctica    | SGS  | South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands |          0 |
| North America | SPM  | Saint Pierre and Miquelon                    |       7000 |
| Oceania       | UMI  | United States Minor Outlying Islands         |          0 |
| Europe        | VAT  | Holy See (Vatican City State)                |       1000 |
+---------------+------+----------------------------------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use group by like this:

```
SELECT Name,Population FROM Country WHERE Population=
(SELECT MIN(Population) FROM   Country GROUP BY Continent);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unless I have understood something wrong, it doesn't works. First of all the subquery returns more than one row so it cannot by executed, I guess you wanted to put the last ) after Country, that way it works but with the least total inhabited countries in all the world not in each continent, and just shows one country per continent.